# Raycast doesn't point on the right direction

Tags: unity, raycasting, unityscript

The raycast line im rendering is acting weird, it doesn't point where I want it to.

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/83a25c9e3118982fbd9779199d2d35be.png]

I want it to point from the yellow object to the selected one but it draws it at another position.

Here is my script:

```
    #pragma strict

var player : Transform;
var turret : Transform;

var bullet : Transform;
var barrelEnd : Transform;

var shootRate = 0.3;

var canShoot : boolean = true;

var soundEffect : AudioClip;

function Update()
{
    shoot();
}

function shoot()
{
    turret.LookAt(player);
    var hit : RaycastHit;
    var fwd = turret.forward;
    if(Physics.Raycast(turret.position, player.position,hit, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        if(hit.collider.transform.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            if(canShoot == true)
            {
                var bulletInstance : Transform;
                bulletInstance = Instantiate(bullet, barrelEnd.position, transform.rotation);
                bulletInstance.LookAt(player.position);
                audio.PlayOneShot(soundEffect);
                w();
            }
        }
    }

    Debug.DrawRay(player.position, transform.position);
}

function w()
{
    canShoot=false;
    yield WaitForSeconds(shootRate);
    canShoot=true;
}
```

Thank you! I hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the [`RayCast`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) and [`DrawRay`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) methods incorrectly. Both call for a direction for their second parameter, and you're passing in a position.

In the case of the `RayCast` you probably want your direction to be the `fwd` variable you create using `turret.forward`.

Comment: I really thought I tried that lol ,it seems like I didn't. Anyway, thank you very much for your big help! It works just the way I wanted it to work.

Comment: No problem. Checking the documentation is always a good first step in debugging :).